# Archival strategy : How to Fetch records and maintain data sharing, which was there earlier when the data was inside salesforce?

Tags: sharing, heroku-connect, archive

Salesforce recommends Heroku Connect + postgres for data archiving strategy.
And for fetching the data salesforce recommends Salesforce connect via Odata api.

But when retrieving records via Odata Api, how to retain the sharing for that record? How will salesforce manage this? As the records are in postgres now and the records are getting fetched via Odata Api, how will data sharing be managed here.

Do we also somehow replicate `UserRecordAccess` table? (Some custom way, as Heroku connect says this table is not syncable)

Comment: This depends on your goals and/or how you define _archiving_. Pulling records from archive back into "active" mode, a process known as _rehydration_, is usally implemented as a data restore where records are copied back from archive into the source system.  Trailhead's [recommendation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/connectors-for-data-integration/archive-and-consolidate-salesforce-data) of using Heroku Connect wouldn't be our first choice of implementing archival...but even so external objects support sharing except at a record level, a typical tradeoff.

Comment: @identigral When you say `external objects support sharing except at a record level`, can you please explain or share documentation where is this available. And is it for all connectors?

Comment: There isn't a doc that explicitly spells this out. When we tried this a while ago with Connect, the target (receiving) org respected profile-based access to the object. "Most" other access control would be subject to the provider org and/or the connector. For finer-grained access in the receiving org, Product Mgmt wants to use [Restriction Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_sharing_restriction_rules_external_objects.htm&type=5&release=238).